# How did the Rebels stop the Juggernaut in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In Rogue One, we see Jyn Erso being transported by a HAVw A9 Juggernaut to the Imperial labor camp when the Rebels rescue her.

Assuming that the A9 is about the same size as the A6, then it should be massive and well armed. The 5 or 6 rebels we see attack it should have been dead.

**How did the Rebels stop the Juggernaut?**

Comment: Maybe they had, you know, a super cool Imperial security droid to flag it down for them and draw the crew out?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the Rebel Alliance wanted to keep it a secret because the procedure has not been revealed in detail. It must have been a well-planned and successful ambush of some kind since nothing ominous can be seen in front of the Juggernaut(s), in either the movie or the graphic novel adaptation.

[image]

[image]

It's possible the Rebel agents tricked the transport(s) to stop pretending to be another prisoner pick-up. Maybe K-2SO played a role here. At least this was the first impression of the stormtroopers.

> "What now?"
>
> "I don't know. Must be another pick-up."
>
> "I thought we had everybody."

Anyhow, the Juggernaut(s) were not stopped by force, but the Rebels initially used some sort of stealth tactics instead. The screen in the comic book shows there's no superficial damage on either one of the tanks.

[image]

Interestingly there were two turbo tanks in the graphic novel, as the movie gave an impression of there being only one. Given that, Jyn was most likely held in the first one, which means that the Rebels must have stopped and controlled them both.